# Importing .DAT file to Database?

Tags: c#, sql, database

How would I go about import/inserting a .DAT file into the database by calling a procedure?

Here's what my file would look like and it has to go into the database in this format.

```
50  4411902304  1   3   441192304   01/02/2013
```

Would the process be the same for .DAT file as to xml file?

Here's what I have for xml

```
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=name;" +
                                   "password=password;server=servername;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=database; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

        var conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "user id=idName;" +
                                   "password=password;" + "server=servername;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=databasename; " +  "connection timeout=30";


        string filePath = "C:/TestData2.xml";
        string xml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procedureName"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", xml);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("done");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that XML is a new technology compared to the old flat file (DAT). 
XML is a markup format file and there are functions implemented to make easier the importing tasks.
Flat file are older, so a different approach is needed.

You can use the bcp (bulk copy program) to import files to SQL Server or the SSIS Import options.

Or, you can also use:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\data\TestData2.dat");
int counter = 0;
while ((line = (file.ReadLine())) != null){...}
```

And parsing each line using the Split command.

```
string[] fields= line.Split(' ');
```

`string a = fields[0];`
`string b = fields[1];`
`string c = fields[2];`

and then execute a command to insert each line:

```
string sqlCommandtoInsert= "INSERT INTO [Table] (Tablefield1, Tablefield2, Tablefield3) VALUES (" + a + ", " + b + ", '" + c + "');";
```

`cmd.CommandText = sqlCommandtoInsert;`

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Inserting each record in your table.